# angular js attach multiple controllers to routprovider

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I am using two controllers in single .js file. i am using angular route for my application. how to attached multiple controllers to route config.

my main.js

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.controller('MainController', function($scope, close, title, $sce) {


});

app.controller('ModalController', function($scope, close, title, $sce) {
  //console.log("sdsd");

  if ((title.headers('Content-Type')).includes("pdf")) {
    $scope.pdfitem = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('data:application/pdf;base64,' + title.data);
  } else {
    $scope.imageitem = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('data:image/JPEG;base64,' + title.data);
  }

  $scope.close = function(result) {
    close(result, 500); // close, but give 500ms for bootstrap to animate
  };

});
```

can i add multiple controllers like below or what is the correct way

```js
.when('/customer-details', {
  templateUrl: 'customer_details.jsp',
  controller: 'cutomerController',
  'MainController'
})
```

Comment: no you can not add multiple controllers like they way you are tyring. Instead in your html template you can use `ng-controller` to assign a controller to a div and like that you can have multiple divs each having different controller in one single view/route